# Changing Context Menu's width results in poor rendering

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, width, contextmenu, actualwidth

All I wanted to do is have a `ContextMenu` on a `Button` with the width bounded to the `Button`'s width. Apparently that's too much. If you open the `ContextMenu` and then decrease the size of the `Button` and open it again everything's OK (the `Width` gets smaller). If you increase the `Width` (from 100 to 200 for example) the `ContextMenu`'s `Width` increases too (to 200) but it only renders the previous `Width` (100). I changed the `Width` myself in code, used `ActualWidth` instead but though the values seem fine, the context menu's rendering is poor.

Comment: Tried everything i can think about, even used ScaleTransform but nothing works. I think it's probably a bug that no one came across because no one changes the size of their context menus.

Answer (score 1):

The width of the context menu seems to be driven by the text field length of the context item with the longest text field.

If you append a bunch of spaces to one of the context item's text field this makes both that context item and the whole context menu wider.

Everything then draws fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies, but do you have the option to use the `SnapToDevicePixels=True`? I have found this makes a massive difference in rendering when it is not used... but I am not sure if the option is available on your context menu.

Comment: I do have the option, but it has no affect.
I also tried to replace the ItemsPanelTemplate but it still rendered only a part of the ContextMenu